# Additional criteria to symfony filter

Tags: symfony1, filter, symfony-1.4, criteria, pager

i'm working on a symfony project to manage a database. First i explain how it works:

In the database, all elements are associated to an unique element 'scene'. When a user accesses the application, chooses what scene he wants to see (it saves that in a user parameter). So when listing elements, the application should only list elements associated with the scene selected by the user.

*Note: all elements have an scene attribute in the table definition.

So my problem comes here:

I developed a listing of an element entities using the help of a sfPropelPager class to paginate. Also added some filters to search in the list, and for that i used the filter system provided by symfony (`<element>FormFilter.class.php` and stuff).

Now i want the list to not show elements from other scenes than the selected by the user.

How can i do to add additional criteria to the criteria given by the filter class?
or How would you solve the problem?

### here is my action code:

```
  public function executeUnidadfilter(sfWebRequest $request){
    $this->filter = new BaUnidadorganizativaTblFormFilter();
    $c = $this->filter->getCriteria();
    $this->filter->bind($request->getParameter($this->filter->getName()));
    if($this->filter->isValid()){
      $this->pager = new sfPropelPager('BaUnidadorganizativaTbl',$this->sfPropelPagerLines);
      echo $this->getUser()->getEscenario();
      $this->pager->setCriteria($c);
      $this->pager->init();
   }else{
      $this->pager = new sfPropelPager('BaUnidadorganizativaTbl',$this->sfPropelPagerLines);
      $this->pager->init();
   }
   $this->setTemplate('Unidadlist');
 }
```

*Note: 'scene' mentioned below is Escenario in the code

thank you very much for your time

Comment: Could you post the action executeIndex used to list your items?

Comment: As the variable i want to filter to is a field of the filtered table, this could be done adding a widget for the field, and somehow, specifiyng a value (unchangable) given as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The trouble was that i assigned the formfilter generated criteria to my criteria var Before the filter was filled. That's why of the error.

The resulting code is that:

```
  public function executeUnidadfilter(sfWebRequest $request){
    $this->filter = new BaUnidadorganizativaTblFormFilter();
    $this->filter->bind($request->getParameter($this->filter->getName()));
    if($this->filter->isValid()){
        $this->pager = new sfPropelPager('BaUnidadorganizativaTbl',$this->sfPropelPagerLines);
        $esc = $this->getUser()->getEscenario();
        $c = new Criteria();
        $c = $this->filter->getCriteria();
        $c->addAnd('codigo_escenario',$esc);
        $this->pager->setCriteria($c);
        $this->pager->init();
    }else{
        $this->pager = new sfPropelPager('BaUnidadorganizativaTbl',$this->sfPropelPagerLines);
        $this->pager->setCriteria($this->filter->getCriteria());
        $this->pager->init();
    }
    $this->message=null;
    $this->messageType=null;
    $this->setTemplate('Unidadlist');
 }
```

Comment: I'm reading your post right now. Happy to hear you have solved the problem!